# Problema de transición

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a problem when it comes to making a transition for a design that I am taking as a basis for a project.
The problem is that, when I press the register button, it should show the registration section by means of a scroll to the left and it does not do so.

I want to know how I could fix the problem and know if it is any error in the id .

```js
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const logInButton = document.getElementById('logIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
});

logInButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: #0E1119;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Lobster',cursive;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -20px 0 50px;
}

h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span{
    font-size: 12px;
}

a{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3F2EFF;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active{
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus{
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

button.ghost:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: #0E1119;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


input{
    background: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.log-in-container{
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;

}

.container.right-panel-active.log-in-container{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container{
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active.sign-up-container{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {

    0%,
    49.99%{
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%,
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }

}

.overlay-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active.overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay{
    background: #FF416C;
    background: linear-gradient(142.18deg, #37ff48 0%, #36fef7 98.85%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active.overlay{
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left{
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active.overlay-left{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.overlay-right{
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active.overlay-right{
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
.social-container{
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a{
    border: 1px solid #1a9889;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styLogin.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="container">

    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Crear cuenta</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>Usa tu correo para registrarte</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre"/>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Correo"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            <button id="btnR">Registrarme</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <div class="form-container log-in-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>

            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>Usar cuenta</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Correo"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            <a href="#">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña? </a>
            <button>Iniciar sesión</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <div class="overlay-container">

        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                <h1>¡Bienvenido de nuevo!</h1>
                <p>¿Ya tienes una cuenta? Inicia sesión</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="logIn">Iniciar sesión</button>

            </div>

            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                <h1>¡Ey hola!</h1>
                <p>¿No tienes una cuenta? ¡Crea una gratis!</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registrarme</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="log.js"></script>

</body>





</html>
```

Comment: Please use English in the title.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_ + [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const logInButton = document.getElementById('logIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
});

logInButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: #0E1119;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Lobster',cursive;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -20px 0 50px;
}

h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span{
    font-size: 12px;
}

a{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3F2EFF;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active{
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus{
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

button.ghost:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: #0E1119;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


input{
    background: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.log-in-container{
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;

}

.right-panel-active .log-in-container{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container{
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.right-panel-active .sign-up-container{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {

    0%,
    49.99%{
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%,
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }

}

.overlay-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay{
    background: #FF416C;
    background: linear-gradient(142.18deg, #37ff48 0%, #36fef7 98.85%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.right-panel-active .overlay{
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left{
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.right-panel-active .overlay-left{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.overlay-right{
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.right-panel-active .overlay-right{
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
.social-container{
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a{
    border: 1px solid #1a9889;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styLogin.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="container">

    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Crear cuenta</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>Usa tu correo para registrarte</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre"/>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Correo"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            <button id="btnR">Registrarme</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <div class="form-container log-in-container">
        <form action="#">
            <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>

            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>Usar cuenta</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Correo"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            <a href="#">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña? </a>
            <button>Iniciar sesión</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <div class="overlay-container">

        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                <h1>¡Bienvenido de nuevo!</h1>
                <p>¿Ya tienes una cuenta? Inicia sesión</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="logIn">Iniciar sesión</button>

            </div>

            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                <h1>¡Ey hola!</h1>
                <p>¿No tienes una cuenta? ¡Crea una gratis!</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registrarme</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="log.js"></script>

</body>





</html>
```

I edited in CSS.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: You made a mistake with the CSS selectors. You can learn the difference between them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858298/in-css-is-a-b-different-than-a-b